# Is it possible to display a python game window (or any file window) in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

**Question:** Is there a way to make a Python game window display within Unity rather than opening a new window outside of Unity?

**Context:** I have an assignment which is making a game in Unity 3D and I'm not enjoying it all that much. I have found great success and joy in creating games using the Python Arcade library when compared with Unity and the progress I make in Python is staggering compared.

I haven't tried all that much as this seems to be a pretty special problem but I will search.

**Expected Outcome:** I want to be able to display the Python game through an in-Unity sprite such as an arcade machine sprite which the Python game window will be displayed on/in. It is important that the Python game will be displayed in Unity just in case I may be able to get away with this for my assignment, and that a player can interact with the Python game through controls in Unity.

Comment: If you say that you don't have that much success with c#, then why use python? the assignment is for you to learn the language. if you use python you won't learn anything, especially if you already know python. i would suggest to just go for c# and not try to cheat at the assignment. also to the questions itself: that wouldn't be too easy. I guess it's much harder than just going for c#

Comment: Fair enough. I believe the task was more aimed at the process of planning, documenting and implementing what we've learnt about projects with modularity, top-down structuring and so-on as the course we're doing doesn't really focus much on coding and the C# is just something to work through, but this gave me an idea to not just have the python game inside Unity but to have a Unity game including the python games. I'd make an arcade inside Unity with python games as basic fillers and the main game(s) as C# game(s). So I'd still like to get an idea on whether my question is possible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to open the unity game and what the user sees is only the python game? You could just 'fake' it by running the splashscreen and copying the unity directory structure and so on. But as this is an assignment, wouldn't it be reviewed and they will see that it wasn't just with unity but with python? I don't fully understand you question right

Comment: I think you understand the question right, but I just thought that there may have been a loophole in the assigning of the assignement I could exploit to use a Python game. But I think as long as there's a base C# Unity game underneath with actual content like the arcade game idea I had, I may be able to get away with it without any/much questioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for it more likely to be 10x more complex than writing a simple arcade game. Not meaning to diss your favourite game library but unity is fantastic and trying to avoid learning the basics of it is simply a mistake.

While there are few thing 'not possible' within unity, embedding a view rendered by something completely different like a python framework sounds like weeks of work - where as writing a game on an assignment level once you grasp the basics is more like a few hours

Comment: I believe you're right and it does make sense that it's difficult to run Python in C# or do whoever would have to be done to do something like what I wanted. I'll take this as an opportunity to learn a new language. Thank you.

Comment: while C# might have some downsides (very verbose compared to python) it does have some really sweet sides, by having strong typing it prevents you from doing a whole class of human errors, you start to appreciate later, as complexity grows and

Comment: Would you have any places to continue learning after my assignment is done or should I stick with the free side of CodeCademy?

Comment: there's tons and tons of good learning material for unity, hard to really recommend a single source, reading other peoples projects (github is full of them) and own experimentation would me my favourites, for me getting to know unity to a certain point was a life-changing event, suddenly starting to code for living became a valid option